# spring security authentification

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I try to use Spring Security for an application which has 3 kinds of users: Admin, employee, and responsible. each one must be redirected after his authentication to his jsp pages which are grouped in a folder
this is my spring configuration but it doesn't work:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/responsable*" access="ROLE_RESP" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/employee*" access="ROLE_EMP" />
</http>

 <authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="admin" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <user name="resp" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_RESP" />
    <user name="emp" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_EMP" />
    </user-service>
   </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

  </beans:beans>
```

and this is my web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>projet</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>

   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>responsable/responsable.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>employee/employee.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
     <!-- Spring Security -->
   <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
  </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

     <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
   </listener>
   <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
 </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Comment: You added the spring security filter in your web.xml ?

Comment: More specific patterns are defined higher in the list than less specific patterns :

try this :

 `
    <intercept-url pattern="/responsable*" access="ROLE_RESP" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/employee*" access="ROLE_EMP" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: are there any error messages displayed in your console

Comment: the authentification of Admin is successful but for the others it gives : Access is denied

Comment: the problem is caused by the order of your <intercept-url> try to change the order like I told you, and clean, restart your server its must work.

Comment: If it's not going expected jsp page, then to which page it is redirecting to. Or you are getting any error.

Comment: I changed the order of <intercept-url> but it gives also Access is denied !

Comment: thers is no error in console juste in the browser I still  have Access is denied for the employee and responsible, should I use a java class to determinate redirection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sad,
You are trying to use spring security as a re-director rather than its actual purpose. What your spring security definition means is that you are granting different users different levels of entitlements. So while Admin can visit every URL of your app, an employee may only have access to any area that begins with /employee URL. The actual redirection will happen within your Disptacher Servlet/Controller configuration. Thanks.